# Difference between setWindowAnimations and overridePendingTransition?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

What is the difference between,

```
getWindow().setWindowAnimations()
```

and

```
Activity.overridePendingTransition()
```

It seems like both have the same functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we are using

```
getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.anim.start);
```

then this animation works when window is opening, but in this type of method we can't add window closeing animation.

But using

```
Activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.start,R.anim.end);
```

this We can show animation when window is closeing
First parameter of this method is starting animation
And Second parameter of this method is ending animatin.

So the diffrence between above methods is 
overridePendingTransition() is use to set starting and ending animation to activity. 
setWindowAnimations is use to set only starting animation.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation :)